# Setting parameters for a factor

Tags: r

I am having trouble setting the parameters for a factor and would appreciate some help. I want to make a dummy variable where it is equal to 0 when a variable equals five different points and 1 for all others. So far I have tried the following:

```
htd$CBSA = factor(with(data = htd, ifelse(( cbsa==41460|16980|35620|37980|14460),0,1)))
```

and

```
htd$CBSA = as.numeric(htd$cbsa == 41460|16980|35620|37980|14460)
```

and tried any combination of , and "" in place of the | and don't know where to go.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
> 1 == 3
[1] FALSE
> 1 == 3 | 1 == 2
[1] FALSE
> 1 == 3 | 2
[1] TRUE
```

You want `%in%`:

```
> 1 %in% c(3, 2)
[1] FALSE
> 1 %in% c(3, 1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand how to use this or what it is doing differently

Comment: I want to make a dummy variable with all five of those numbers (41460, 16980, etc) in one group and the rest in another; I can get it to work with one number but don't know how to add additional values. The only info I can find on this is for a single number or using an inequality, which I dont want.

Comment: I have used it a lot but only for things which I learned specifically how to do

Comment: Apply what I said: `Dummy = htd$cbsa %in% c(41460, 16980, 35620, 37980, 14460)`